# Changing date from query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a query (written to be easier from a class)

```
 $cms->my_query('SELECT * FROM location');
```

Which will return an array

Though I have a DATE type in the mySQL Table which it is formatted like so `2014-06-22`

Is there a way I can format so it's like this `Nov 04 2008 11:45 PM` with using `DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%b %d %Y %h:%i %p")` now I believe DATE cannot use this properly so i'd have to use DATETIME but if that is the case it's fine but how do I select all and change date at the same time?

**Example**

```
 $cms->my_query('SELECT * FROM location DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%b %d %Y %h:%i %p")');
```

I just don't want that ugly `2014-06-22` and I have very little knowledge of mySQL and I am learning as I try new things out. So if someone who is more skilled please explain the best scenario for me, I'd like to learn and I am willing!

Comment: Are you wanting to format and return the current date, ie `NOW()`, or a date that is stored in a column in the table?

Comment: Date that is stored in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `DATE_FORMAT()` is the date you want to format. Putting `NOW()` in there means you will return the current date.

First, you'll need to change the date column to `DATETIME`, then use that column as the first argument to `DATE_FORMAT`. Try this:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(mydate ,"%b %d %Y %h:%i %p") as date_added FROM location
```

Where `mydate` is the `DATETIME` column from the table.

[**See demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc506/1)

Comment: that of course returns cur_date I want formatted date to the date that the information was "added".

Comment: this worked for me Mark `$cms->my_query('SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(`date`,"%b %d %Y %h:%i %p") as date FROM `newsPost`');` which is what you had I just changed the `as date_added` to `as date`

Comment: @EasyBB Great! Ya, the `as ...` part could be anything - whatever you want to refer to the returned date value as.

Comment: Thank you so much, now if you could so kindly point me to some documentation on how to use and when to use the `as` keyword?

Comment: @EasyBB You could start [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html). It's very simple, though. `as` just gives the selected column a new identifier. Without it, the returned column would be called `DATE_FORMAT(mydate, "%b %d %y %h:%i %p")`. Adding `as date` means you can just refer to it as the much simpler string `date`. It can be anything though - `as banana` would name that column `banana`. Have a look at [**this**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fc506/5) - it might be helpful.

Comment: Lol Thank you, that actually helped sir. Have a good one and thanks again for helping me and understanding my question.

Answer (score 1):

The column need to be in type `DATETIME`. With `date_time_column` is a column in `location` table. Should be like this:

```
$cms->my_query('SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_time_column,"%m-%d-%Y %r") FROM location');
```

Comment: Still formatted the same. Do i have to change the DATE to DATETIME?

Comment: Actually, use double quotes for `%m-%d-%Y %r` since you're using single quotes on the query

Comment: Same return. I have 5.2.* could that be the case?

Comment: You need to use DATETIME for that column. DATE will ignore the time part when save.

Comment: Use the column in DATE_FORMAT function :) Try & see